# How does this `if not` statement work without parentheses in a new service application?

Tags: delphi, if-statement, service

When creating a new Windows Service in Delphi, it inserts the following:

```
if not Application.DelayInitialize or Application.Installing then
  Application.Initialize;
```

The author didn't bother including parentheses, so I'm trying to wrap my head around this. It translates to:

```
if (not Application.DelayInitialize) or Application.Installing then
  Application.Initialize;
```

From what I understand, if both `Application.DelayInitialize` and `Application.Installing` are `True`, then it will go ahead and `Initialize` the service application. I don't understand *why* it would be initialized in this scenario - I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be initialized.

Can someone give me some clarification what I'm looking at here?

---

On a side note, I would never need to enable `DelayInitialize` as there's no need to be concerned with Server 2003. I would just like to understand what this code is actually meant to do the way it's written.

Comment: `not` operator has higher [precedence](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operator_Precedence).

Comment: Looks like `Application.DelayInitialize` can postpone initialization, but `Application.Installing` overrides that, so even if `DelayInitialize` is set, it will still initialize the application when it is installing. Bit hard to tell if that was indeed the intention, but I would interpret it like that. Your conclusions are right, btw. It's indeed the same as the second variation, with `not` only applying to the first bool. And as LU RD mentioned, that's documented behavior.

Comment: Jerry, it's like @LURD says, it's determined by operator precedence.  One way to think about that is that operators of higher precedence bind "more tightly" than lower ones.  So in your expression, `not bool1` is evaluated before the `or bool2` gets a chance to get a look in.  Not my dv, btw.  See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operator_Precedence

Comment: Jerry, think of it like a mathematical expression: `y = 2*x +a`. The multiplicator operator has higher precedence than the addition operator.

Comment: *"... some clarification what I'm looking at here?"* That's the problem, it's not clear. With all that unnecessary testing code it looks like you're trying to figure out operator precedence (hence the downvotes) while in fact you're probably (?) asking about service application initialization.

Comment: IMHO it's not there yet. *"I can see this possibly meaning two things"* No need for that - and the following tests, what it means is clearly defined. Just ask the service, I'm sure David will not be upset about the wasted answer. BTW, I find your testing method a little bit inefficient, normally you'd just pause the debugger and type "not false or false" etc. in a watch.

Comment: I was just trying to be thorough and prove that I have attempted to test and validate the behavior.

Comment: Yes. I take full responsibility of upcoming downvotes. <g>

Comment: Clearly you were asking about operator precedence. Anyway, at least you now know how to find the documentation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment inserted in the project source when you create a service application explains, [`DelayInitialize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.SvcMgr.TServiceApplication.DelayInitialize) exists for a specific reason: the requirement to call [`StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-startservicectrldispatchera) before [`CoRegisterClassObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coregisterclassobject). Whether you would need to set it or not, I presume, would really depend on if you need to call `CoRegisterClassObject`, not if you're targeting server 2003 or not <sup>(*)</sup>. IOW, I wouldn't expect that comment to be updated with every new server version. YMMV, testing might be required.

The implied design here is that you use [`System.InitProc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.InitProc) to call `CoRegisterClassObject` <sup>(**)</sup>, similar to how the `CoInitializeEx` call is made by ComObj.pas. `InitProc` is called from `Vcl.Forms.Application.Initialize` which is called from `Vcl.SvcMgr.TServiceApplication.Initialize`.

Now, when `Vcl.SvcMgr.TServiceApplication.Installing` returns true, that means `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` will not to be called. Because the main thread is not going to connect with the service control manager. Instead it will either install or uninstall services and then exit. Then the need for any delayed initialization will become void and in fact a delayed initialization cannot run since no service thread will run <sup>(***)</sup>.

And so this is why the expression is written the way it is, there are no forgotten/missing parenthesis.

---

<sup>(*) D2007 has the comment at which time 2003 R2 is the last server.</sup>

<sup>(**) From the comment in the project source:</sup>

<sup>*Windows 2003 Server requires StartServiceCtrlDispatcher to be called before CoRegisterClassObject, which can be called indirectly by Application.Initialize.*</sup>

<sup>(***) This is where a delayed initialization is called, guarded by a flag in case there is more than one service in the executable.</sup>